Convert json data to comma separated string
I have a json object that has an unknown number of variables, like this:
{ 
  "var1": 123, 
  "var2": 456, 
  "var3": 789 
}

How can I automatically convert it to form the following string?
'var1=123,var2=456,var3=789'

Note, I am looking for a solution that doesn't require installing jq.

Will it always be this simple? Exactly one set of { }, then pairs of quoted string with no spaces, an :, one space, numbers and a comma?

@terdon Yes it will.

jq is a versatile tool - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq for some possibilities.

Miller might be even easier, since the output you want appears to be in exactly the default DKVP format. So it could be as simple as mlr --ijson cat input.json .

Without installing jq: docker run -i --rm ghcr.io/jqlang/jq -r 'to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value)") | "'\''\(join(","))'\''"' <file

If it will always be this simple, something like this might work
tr : = | tr -d '{}"\n ' | sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"

In parts:

translate : to =
remove all other extra characters including punctuation, spaces, newlines
add single quote at start and end


What if the variables are strings, which might contain {} etc?

@Vilinkameni This is not the case in my application. There will be no special characters like that in the strings. The answer provided works perfectly for me.

This is the simplest answer.  It's not the best answer.  OP said it would always be simple, so there are a lot of cases this won't work for.  I like the other answers.  I'm disappointment (but not surprised) there isn't a shorter answer.

If you don't care about the order of the object members:
$ perl -CO -MJSON::PP -l -0777 -ne '
  $j = decode_json($_);
  print join ",", map("$_=$j->{$_}", keys %$j)' your-file
var3=789,var2=456,var1=123

perl comes pre-installed on most systems, and JSON::PP is one its built-in modules.
Or if your system has python3:
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python3 -c '
import json, sys;
_ = json.load(sys.stdin);
print(",".join(map(lambda i: "%s=%s" % i, _.items())))' < your-file

(the order should be preserved as python3's dictionaries contrary to perl's hashes do keep track of an order of keys).
With a less tamed input such as:
{
  "var-\"ⓧ\"": 1e-2,
  "var=v,v": "\n",
  "var\uD83E\uDDD9": null
}

They give
var=v,v=
,var-"ⓧ"=0.01,var=

And
var-"ⓧ"=0.01,var=v,v=
,var=None

Respectively, while mlr --ijson cat gives:
var-"ⓧ"=1e-2,var=v,v=
,var=null

And jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value)")|join(",")' gives:
var-"ⓧ"=0.01,var=v,v=
,var=null

(though neither jq nor mlr are generally installed by default).

Any reason why you're not just sorting the keys, as in print join ",", map"$_=$j->{$_}", sort keys %$j?

@kos, sounds like the var1, var2 in the sample are just placeholders for the actual values. While sorting the keys lexically here (which could also be done using the canonical JSON:PP option) would happen to restore the original order in the sample, it wouldn't in the general case.

Ok, I see the point, thanks (obviously you know and just got confused in the comment but for others: canonical only works while encoding, once the keys are stored into a hash the order is lost no matter what, so sorting would be needed in order to sort the values in the output)

@kos, ah yes, sorry, canonical wouldn't help indeed as we're not encoding. Thanks for the correction.

One option to do this with awk will looks like:
awk '!/{/ && !/}/ {gsub("\"","");gsub(":","=");gsub(" ","");printf "%s",$0}' input_file

This command expect { and } to be the only symbols on the line and the rest of the format to be strict
If you want to have new line at the end you can use command:
awk '!/{/ && !/}/ {gsub("\"","");gsub(":","=");gsub(" ","");printf "%s",$0} END {printf "\n"}' input_file

